# groovy - collate maps in list of maps

Tags: groovy

What is the simplest way to combine several maps in list elements into one map. For instance: list1 -> list2

```
def list1 = [[a:'apple'],[b:'orange'],[c:'pear'],[a:'watermelon'],[b:'banana'],[c:'grape'],[a:'lychee'],[b:'guava'],[c:'starfruit']]

def list2 = [[a:'apple', b:'orange', c:'pear'],[a:'watermelon', b:'banana', c:'grape'],[a:'lychee', b:'guava', c:'starfruit']]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
list1.groupBy{it.values()[0].intdiv(10)}.collect{it.value.collectEntries()}
```

Comment: Hi Evgeny, this indeed give the result, but if those values in the map are string instead of int, is there any other workaround?

Comment: change it.values()[0].intdiv(10) to it.values()[0].toInteger().intdiv(10)

Comment: I mean some random non-numeric strings or numbers that doesn't follow the 1, 11, 21 pattern

Comment: Then you must create other grouping criteria depending on what you want)

Comment: Thanks Evgeny, I've figured it out. It turns out to be very simple. My solution: list1.collate(3).collect { it.collectEntries() }